# How do I tell GCC to either not initialize the stack during _start, or manually set it?

Tags: c, gcc, arm64

I'm using the aarch64-none-eabi toolchain.  The start code seems to be resetting the stack pointer to 0, even though the stack pointer is already configured when I call the code.  If I jump and start execution 3 or 4 instructions in, past the stack pointer initialization, it works fine.

Comment: How are _you_ calling `_start` [at all]? When you build an (e.g.) ELF executable, the actual start address is encoded in a special section. The default is to use a standard/provided function, and it's usually/sometimes called `_start`. It takes the stack pointer from whatever the kernel/ELF loader sets it to, sets up some things, and then calls `main`. Are you in some sort of standalone [non-POSIX] environment? What are you doing exactly (and why?)? Do you have the source to the start function in question?

Comment: You will need to write your own startup code and link with `-nostartfiles`

Comment: It's being called from U-Boot using its go command.  The _start function is being linked right to the beginning of the image, so I can just pass that address in.  I don't have the source to the start function, it's just the default one that is part of the CRT.

Comment: Well, that's why @EugeneSh. recommended to use that option. It will stop the linker from linking a start function from the library. You need to provide your own.